# The Visual Studio 2022 Net Framework 4.8 clickonce published result does not open, but the normal result has no problems

Tags: clickonce, .net-4.8

I have a Net Framework 4.8 app. My app is inside bin\debug folder. The normal .exe output has no problem. But the debug\app.publish output can't be opened. Does not show any errors, and there are no log files here inside my project. It can't even show any tasks in Task Manager. What can I do to open the clickonce published output? I need an answer because the output has a digital certificate.**If someone wants more detail, I can publish!**

**What i tried?**

> > Looked at event viewer. I can't found anything because i don't know how to use event viewer
> > Deleted app.publish folder. Still not works.
> > Open as administrator and check permissions. Still nothing.

Comment: btw clickonce result was working before and defender wall does not dedect a malware inside clickonce result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.